# Unable to install/run cloudflared

Tags: networking, server, dns, executable, https

I have been setting up Pi-hole today and want to use Cloudflared for DNS-over-HTTPS. I have tried a couple different tutorials but I always get stuck on using `cloudflared --version`.

```
pi@pi-hole:~ $ ls
cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb  Desktop  Documents  Downloads  MagPi  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
pi@pi-hole:~ $ sudo apt-get install ./cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cloudflared:amd64' instead of './cloudflared-stable-linux-amd64.deb'
cloudflared:amd64 is already the newest version (2019.10.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
pi@pi-hole:~ $ sudo cloudflared --version
sudo: unable to execute /usr/local/bin/cloudflared: No such file or directory
pi@pi-hole:~ $ cd /
pi@pi-hole:/ $ cd usr/local/bin
pi@pi-hole:/usr/local/bin $ ls -l
total 38216
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 39114256 Oct 21 15:00 cloudflared
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14655 Oct 23 09:27 pihole
```

I am running Raspberry Pi Desktop in a Xenserver virtual machine.

```
pi@pi-hole:/usr/local/bin $ uname -m
x86_64
pi@pi-hole:/usr/local/bin $ file cloudflared
cloudflared: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, Go BuildID=YvLL9ax0IXHPa3ehgMdM/cni8ZTgd4Q12MDeKtPvI/3MjRiWDil4zJKPjW8Bhe/XMFlqqYnI277kgIRSLdT, BuildID[sha1]=23942fcd1bb134ccd737c1ff188006eb3d0a4a6a, not stripped
pi@pi-hole:/usr/local/bin $
```

As far as I can tell I have the correct executable for my OS. Any suggestions?

I have looked at these tutorials for reference:

- https://docs.pi-hole.net/guides/dns-over-https/
- https://polarclouds.co.uk/pi-hole-https-dns/
- https://scotthelme.co.uk/securing-dns-across-all-of-my-devices-with-pihole-dns-over-https-1-1-1-1/

EDIT 11/11/19
I have tried the systemd script. Here is the error I get when I try to start the service:

```
pi@pi-hole:~ $ sudo systemctl start cloudflared
Job for cloudflared.service failed because of unavailable resources or another system error.
See "systemctl status cloudflared.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
pi@pi-hole:~ $ sudo systemctl status cloudflared.service
● cloudflared.service - cloudflared DNS over HTTPS proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/cloudflared.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: resources) since Mon 2019-11-11 18:28:51 CST; 3s ago

Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: cloudflared.service: Service RestartSec=10s expired, scheduling restart.
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: cloudflared.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 9.
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: Stopped cloudflared DNS over HTTPS proxy.
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: cloudflared.service: Failed to load environment files: No such file or directory
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: cloudflared.service: Failed to run 'start' task: No such file or directory
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: cloudflared.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Nov 11 18:28:51 pi-hole systemd[1]: Failed to start cloudflared DNS over HTTPS proxy.
```

Seems to stem from the same error I see trying to run cloudflared where it says no such file or directory.

Comment: Have you installed the systemd script as in the first tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I just added more information to address your question. For some reason it does not want to run the program, thinking it does not exist. Is it possible that the issue is because I am running Raspbian on x86 hardware (its in a VM)? Raspbian on Raspberry Pi is typically an ARM CPU.